# How to write simple Service Bean xml in Java for JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, configuration

I can't find the syntax anywhere for this.  I simply need to define 2 services in a new app.  Previously they were defined in an xml file like:

```
<bean id="service1" class="somePackage.service.service1Impl" />
<bean id="service2" class="somePackage.service.service2Impl" />
```

I want to put these in to a java file.  Is there some simple code I can write to convert these to Java?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to convert their XML definition to Java definition, you will need to create a `@Configuration` class with `@Bean` annotated methods.

```
@Configuration
public class JavaConfig {
    @Bean
    public service1Impl service1() {
        return new service1Impl();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I asked this question correctly.  I simply moved my xml to somewhere that the Class was looking.